# How do I find the BH curve from the frequency-complex permeability relationship?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, complex-numbers, ferromagnetism

I come here after a lot (I mean a lot) of research about complex permeability. I have a ferrite datasheet which give the complex permeability ($\mu'$ and $\mu''$) over frequency.  I don't know how to go from the complex permeability to the $B$-$H$ curve, which turns out to be a ellipse.

How can the complex permeability be represented in the $B$-$H$ plane? It will be helpful for the loss calculation. I don't know why there is not a lot of information about this subject. So a little help will be welcome.

Comment: I'm not an expert in magnetic materials, but my understanding is that the phenomena of complex permability and hysteresis are independent of each other.  That may be why you're unable to find any literature on how they're connected.

Comment: thank you for your answer. there is a link of the two. It's dependent if you take or not hysteresis into account. You can see in this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229028436_Comparison_of_a_simple_and_a_detailed_model_of_magnetic_hysteresis_with_measurements_on_electrical_steel

Comment: https://www.comsol.com/blogs/how-the-b-h-curve-affects-a-magnetic-analysis-and-how-to-improve-it/#:~:text=The%20B%2DH%20curve%20is%20usually,A%2Fm)%2C%20respectively. may be useful

Comment: https://www.nde-ed.org/Physics/Magnetism/HysteresisLoop.xhtml as well

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "complex permeability be represented in the B-H plane". What else do you expect to see besides various ellipses centered at the static operating point and whose  shape and orientation would depend on frequency?

Comment: I eventually found the answer. In sinusoidal or harmonic regime, When there is a lag between magnetic flux H(t) (created by the current) and magnetic flux density B(t), the permeability is complex. If you plot B(t) as a function of H(t), the hysteresis is a ellipse. the hysteresis doesn't into account the saturation